# Gradle sync failed in android due to kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, project

I am not using kotlin in my program, it was working fine unless I update the target version from 26 to 28. I don't know a bit about kotlin. whenever i am trying to sync the gradle files it gives an error :

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModel.getImplements()Ljava/util/List;
```

Why it is happening so ?

My gradle file is :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pr20020897.dms"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Project level gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I think, there is something wrong with android studio itself because I tried to create new project but in that also i am getting the same error.

Comment: check project level `build.gradle`.

Comment: I would suggest not using alpha releases... `28.0.0` was released in September

Comment: @cricket_007 how kotlin related to alpha version ?

Comment: I don't know, but Android 28 isn't related to your error. It's a problem with the Gradle version, not Android.

Comment: ya, but it didn't work.

Comment: maybe try to set gradle buildtool version to `3.2.0`

Comment: @PrakashSharma Have you tried updating gradle to: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` this might help but, It doesn't seem like you're using kotlin so, try gradle update and see what happens.

Comment: @Mohsen yes i did but that also doesn't work

Comment: How about updating kotlin plugin? `File -> settings -> plugins` and do update the kotlin plugin and it should work fine after that I hope.

Comment: ya I am trying that only if it will work i will let you know.

Comment: @Mohsen it works you can post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to update your gradle to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

And in your dependencies, use the stable version:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Since you said you're not using kotlin, Updating the kotlin plugin will help

Go to: `File -> Settings -> Plugins` do update the kotlin then restart.

Comment: Worked like a charm!